# Apache Phoenix Select Random Record

Tags: apache-phoenix

Is there way to write a query that selects a random row from a table?

`SELECT * FROM Foo ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;` always returns the first record in the table.

Also, If I write `SELECT RAND() FROM Foo LIMIT 1` it always shows a random value but it is < 1
e.g:

```
SELECT RAND() FROM Foo LIMIT 1

result 1: 0.5425
result 2:  0.34759
result 3: 0.65478
```

Function [explanation](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/functions.html#rand) already says that it returns between 0.0 and 1.0 but is it possible to write a query that shows a random row from a table? /

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your id column is an autoincremented integer

select * from Foo where id = floor(rand() * num_cols + 0.5)

A more generic answer is to build a query externally and randomly generate an integer outside. This is because phoenix's query parser doesn't allow functions in limit/offset. So generate a random number and plug it into the offset

select * from Foo where limit = 1 offset = ?